# SQL left join part of the array is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, left-join

My problem is the following code the comment&rating area of the array should have a comment in it as the DB history table does ...?

```
 SELECT users.uid, users.username, history.user_id, history.comment, history.rating
 FROM history
 LEFT JOIN users
 ON users.uid=history.user_id
 WHERE history.book_id="$bid"
```

It returns :

```
 Array ( [uid] => 3 [username] => Reign [user_id] => 3 [comment] => [rating] => )
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: it is obviously returning a history record, since history.user_id is 3 in the result. are you sure there's a comment and rating set on that particular record?

Comment: Shouldn't do `="$bid"` either. That's a SQL injection mistake. Should change to `=:bid`.

Answer (score 4):

Then you want to use an `INNER JOIN`. A `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL` values.

```
SELECT users.uid, users.username, history.user_id, history.comment, history.rating
FROM history
INNER JOIN users
ON users.uid=history.user_id
WHERE history.book_id="$bid"
```